# Serving file:// files to users

Tags: security, google-chrome, solr, cross-domain

Currently I'm building a local serach engine for network drives that is going to be used in our company.

The search engine is build on top of Solr and Tika. I've build an indexer that indexes Samba-shares over the network which works great and indexes all the directories that are given in a configuration file. However that is not really relevant.

The current problem we have is that the web interface that connects to Solr and delivers the search results will try to serve local `file://` files that are links to the files with a absolute or Samba path. But serving `file://`'s are of course disallowed by browsers like Google Chrome. The error that Chrome gives is:

```
Not allowed to load local resource: file:///name/to/file.pdf
```

Which is obvious and logical, however I want to work around that issue and serve 'local' files to our users. Or at least open an Explorer window with the given path.

I was wondering if this is even possible or if there is a workaround available? The server that is going to serve these files is running on Apache or Tomcat (doesn't matter).

Answer (score 0):

Alhtough opening `file://`'s seems pretty much impossible without the use of browser-specific plugins, I created a workaround by specifying a custom URI-handler combined with a Windows specific application that will open `explorer.exe` with the given directory.

This is by far not the ideal answer to my question, but I think it is a decent workaround for an intranet search application.

Answer (score 0):

Streaming the file from your application to the browser is a much better idea from a usability and security perspective.

By assigning a MIME type to the stream, the user's browser can decide how best to open and display the file to the user.

By streaming from you application, control of the data can be maintained. The location of the file on you server is not revealed and proper authentication, authorization and auditing are easily achieved.

Assuming Java based upon your use of Solr and Tika:

http://www.java-forums.org/blogs/servlet/668-how-write-servlet-sends-file-user-download.html

Comment: Although this is a good suggestion. I want to expose the location of the file to the user and explicitly want that the user can open this directory.